# FormsAuthentication not working in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, forms-authentication

Can't login on my website using Google Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (64-bit). In Firefox and Internet Explorer it's working.
The website authentication is implemented using FormsAuthentication in ASP.NET MVC 5:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserID.ToString(), true);
```

From my observations:

1. In Firefox .ASPXAUTH cookie is created but in Chrome it's not.

Tried to deploy the website to another server and it is working there. 
Please help find the solution as i need to work with this server.

**Update 1**:

Tried on many computers (from different external IPs), the same problem for all.

**Update 2**:

The same problem in Opera 49.0.

**Update 3**:

Looks like the problem is with expire date:

In Chrome:

[image]

In Firefox:

[image]

**Solution**:

After update of VMware tools to 10287 it is working.

[image]

Comment: I use the same code in an old application and it works fine. There's some bad configuration in your Chrome

Comment: Tried on many computers, the same problem for all.

Comment: I don't know why it is down voted I have the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure  you verify the Chrome settings are in line with those outline here by Google https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647